# XSD to c# generated class results in duplicate namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have 2 XSD files A.xsd and B.xsd and both of them importing a common xsd file C.xsd , upon converting them to C# files using XSD.exe, both of them has classes incuding the classes from C.XSd (common XSD)

Sample Code:
first c# file from xsd 1:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="xyz")]
   public partial class ABC  {
       }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="xyz")]
            public partial class ABC  {
             }
```

This is causing a run time error :

> Types 'First C# file.ABC' and 'Second  C# file.ABC'
>   both use the XML type name, 'ABC', from namespace 'xyz'.
>   Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type

I do not want to change the namespace as the complex types form third party XSD maps to this namespace.

I tried `TypeName Attribute`, but this seems to not work.

Please help me to on this situation.

I am running `xsd.exe` twice because A.xsd and B.xsd are huge files and running them in a single command would result in huge single auto generated C# file, so I wanted to generate separate C# classes for A.xsd and B.xsd.

Comment: grammar, formatting

Comment: What happens if you try [`SvcUtil.exe /serializer:XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe)?

Comment: Also, exactly how are you invoking `xsd.exe`?  Can you show your command line and some simplified XSDs that reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hello, 

Thank you for the response, I used following commands
  > xsd /c common.xsd B.xsd 
  > xsd /c common.xsd  A.xsd

Comment: A.xsd

 <xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/User.xsd" schemaLocation="common.xsd" />
 <xsd:element name="PurchaseOrder" type="tns:PurchaseOrderType"/>
 <xsd:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="ShipTo" type="tns:USAddress" maxOccurs="2"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="OrderDate" type="xsd:date"/>
 </xsd:complexType>

Comment: B.Xsd:

<xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/User.xsd" schemaLocation="common.xsd" />
 
  <xs:complexType name='CustomerType'>  
    <xs:sequence>  
      <xs:element name='CompanyName' type='xs:string'/>  
    
    </xs:sequence>  
    <xs:attribute name='CustomerID' type='xs:token'/>  
  </xs:complexType>

Comment: Common.xsd:

<xsd:element name="UserData" type="tns:UserDetails"/>


 <xsd:complexType name="UserDetails">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="name"   type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:NMTOKEN" fixed="US"/>
 </xsd:complexType>

Comment: Looks like you are running `xsd.exe` twice, thereby generating duplicate versions of the common types.  What if you run it only once and pass in all the schema files on the command line?  `xsd.exe /c common.xsd B.xsd A.xsd`

Comment: Hello Again, Agree with you, but that will generate a single auto generated C# file.

A.xsd and B.xsd are huge files and running them in a single command would result in huge single auto generated C# file, So I wanted to generate separate C# classes for A.xsd and B.xsd  Apologies for not mentioning this before

Comment: Then see [Create MULTIPLE class files based on an XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6654763/3744182).  In fact this appears to be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: Agree this seems duplicate.. 
Your  last two replies answered my complete question ... Thanks a lot for your help on this issue