# Generate multiple C# classes from XSD files

Tags: c#, xsd, code-generation

I have 80 `XSD` files from the Amazon `SP-API` specification.
I want to generate the `C#` classes, but my main problem is that if I use `xsd.exe`, the tool create me only one **HUGE** `.cs` file (42 Mb and 2 million lines of code), and it's impossible to use/open it in Visual Studio.

How can I create **multiple** `.cs` files from these 80 files?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems not possible with Xsd.exe alone but [this answer on Create MULTIPLE class files based on an XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6657610/205233) suggests Resharper to split your resulting monolith into individual .cs files.

Comment: I've tried also Resharper but it doesn't work. I've open a bug to JetBrains https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-484530

Comment: http://www.stylusstudio.com/